# How to add a message and remove it when a select box changes value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a message that alerts a customer when a specific value is selected in a Select Box. My goal is to append this message underneath a description paragraph when `option_2` is selected, and remove the message when any other value is selected.

I'm having two problems:

1. I'm able to get the message to append in my local development (for some reason I cannot get this to work in JSFiddle), but I can't get it to remove
2. Every time`option_2` is selected, another `p` element gets appended, probably a symptom of problem 1.

Here's a fiddle! [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sackadelic/woy7b3da/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<h2>
  Choose an Option:
</h2>
<select id="test">
  <option value="option_1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option_2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option_3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<h3>
  Add Ons:
</h3>
<div class="wc-pao-addon-tone-cap">
  <div class="wc-pao-addon-description">
  <p>
    These are the add ons that you can have:
  </p>
  </div>
  <p>
    <label><input type="checkbox">Add On 1</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label><input type="checkbox">Add On 2</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label><input type="checkbox">Add On 3</label>
  </p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function alertMessage() {
  let toneTwo = document.querySelector('#test');
  let toneCap = document.querySelector('.wc-pao-addon-tone-cap');
  let description = document.querySelector('.wc-pao-addon-description');
  let descriptionParagraph = description.firstChild;


  toneTwo.addEventListener('change', () => {
    if (toneTwo.value == "option_2") {

      const newMessage = document.createElement('p');
      newMessage.innerHTML = '<p class="option-two-alert" style="color: red; margin: 10px 0 0;"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Select Only One Add On When Option 2 Is Selected.</p>';
      descriptionParagraph.appendChild(newMessage);
    } else {
      newMessage.innerHTML = '';
      descriptionParagraph.removeChild(newMessage);
    }
  });
}

window.addEventListener("load", alertMessage);
```

Comment: Kindly check the answer explained the issues too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably be better off by not inserting a new element in to your DOM every time a user selects "option two", instead you should have the element there all the time and make it visible only when option two is selected:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  document.querySelector('#test').addEventListener('change', (ev) => {
    document.querySelector('.option-two-alert').style.display=ev.target.value=="option_2"?'block':'none';
  })
})
```

```css
.option-two-alert {display:none}  /* initially hidden! */
```

```html
<h2>
  Choose an Option:
</h2>
<select id="test">
  <option value="option_1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option_2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option_3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<h3>
  Add Ons:
</h3>
<div class="wc-pao-addon-tone-cap">
  <div class="wc-pao-addon-description">
  <p>
    These are the add ons that you can have:
  </p>
  <p class="option-two-alert" style="color: red; margin: 10px 0 0;">
    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
    Select Only One Add On When Option 2 Is Selected.
  </p>
  </div>
  <p>
    <label><input type="checkbox">Add On 1</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label><input type="checkbox">Add On 2</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label><input type="checkbox">Add On 3</label>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ugh I was totally going about this the wrong way. Thanks for enlightening me!

Answer (score 1):

`firstChild` returns the first child node as an element node, a text node or a comment node which you probably do not want. Try using [`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild).

Change

```
let descriptionParagraph = description.firstChild;
```

To

```
let descriptionParagraph = description.firstElementChild;
```

To remove the message you can use the following code in *else* part

```
let m = document.querySelector('.option-two-alert')
if(m) { m.remove() };
```

**Demo:**

```js
function alertMessage() {
  let toneTwo = document.querySelector('#test');
  let toneCap = document.querySelector('.wc-pao-addon-tone-cap');
  let description = document.querySelector('.wc-pao-addon-description');
  let descriptionParagraph = description.firstElementChild;

  toneTwo.addEventListener('change', () => {
    if (toneTwo.value == "option_2") {
      const newMessage = document.createElement('p');
      newMessage.innerHTML = '<p class="option-two-alert" style="color: red; margin: 10px 0 0;"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Select Only One Add On When Option 2 Is Selected.</p>';
      descriptionParagraph.appendChild(newMessage);
    } else {
      let m = document.querySelector('.option-two-alert')
      if(m) { m.remove(); }
    }
  });
}

window.addEventListener("load", alertMessage);
```

```html
<h2>
  Choose an Option:
</h2>
<select id="test">
  <option value="option_1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option_2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option_3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<h3>
  Add Ons:
</h3>
<div class="wc-pao-addon-tone-cap">
  <div class="wc-pao-addon-description">
  <p>
    These are the add ons that you can have:
  </p>
  </div>
  <p>
    <label><input type="checkbox">Add On 1</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label><input type="checkbox">Add On 2</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label><input type="checkbox">Add On 3</label>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The alert is not added on jsfiddle because the first child of the description there is a TextNode. Try using `firstElementChild`. You also have an issue in the event listener, you never remove the alert. Here's how you can fix it:

```
function alertMessage() {
  let toneTwo = document.querySelector('#test');
  let toneCap = document.querySelector('.wc-pao-addon-tone-cap');
  let description = document.querySelector('.wc-pao-addon-description');
  let descriptionParagraph = description.firstElementChild;
  let newMessage;

  toneTwo.addEventListener('change', () => {
    if (toneTwo.value == "option_2") {

      newMessage = document.createElement('p');
      newMessage.innerHTML = '<p class="option-two-alert" style="color: red; margin: 10px 0 0;"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Select Only One Add On When Option 2 Is Selected.</p>';
      descriptionParagraph.appendChild(newMessage);
    } else if (newMessage) {
      descriptionParagraph.removeChild(newMessage);
    }
  });
}

window.addEventListener("load", alertMessage);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in your code, so will brief it, what the expected output you are looking was when you click on the second option you need to have red text wrapped with i and p tag. That should display below the current p tag `**These are the add ons that you can have:**`

Issues to be fixed

1. `let descriptionParagraph = description.firstChild;` this will give you the text so you were trying to append to this that wont work.
2. `newMessage.innerHTML = '<p class="....` , you can't add like this you need to build the html elements
3. Also you need to have the check `description.childNodes[3] && 
     description.removeChild(description.childNodes[3]);`, assume if the user directly clicks on option_3 that wont have a p tag so you need to consider that case with this check.

I hope you have got a fair idea

Check the below code.

```js
function alertMessage() {
  let toneTwo = document.querySelector('#test');
  let toneCap = document.querySelector('.wc-pao-addon-tone-cap');
  let description = document.querySelector('.wc-pao-addon-description');


  toneTwo.addEventListener('change', () => {
    const newMessage = document.createElement('p');

    if (toneTwo.value == "option_2") {
      let iTag = document.createElement('i');
      iTag.className = 'fas fa-exclamation-circle';
      let pTag = document.createElement('p');
      pTag.style.cssText = "color: red; margin: 10px 0 0";
      let pTagText = document.createTextNode("Select Only One Add On When Option 2 Is Selected.");
      pTag.appendChild(iTag)
      pTag.appendChild(pTagText)
      description.appendChild(pTag)
    } else {
      newMessage.innerHTML = '';
      description.childNodes[3] && 
      description.removeChild(description.childNodes[3]);
    }
  });
}

window.addEventListener("load", alertMessage);
```

```html
<h2>
  Choose an Option:
</h2>
<select id="test">
  <option value="option_1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option_2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option_3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<h3>
  Add Ons:
</h3>
<div class="wc-pao-addon-tone-cap">
  <div class="wc-pao-addon-description">
    <p>
      These are the add ons that you can have:
    </p>
  </div>
  <p>
    <label><input type="checkbox">Add On 1</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label><input type="checkbox">Add On 2</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label><input type="checkbox">Add On 3</label>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation! This is really useful.

Comment: Cool happy to help :)